# android GoogleMap setOnInfoWindowClickListener - abstract method

Tags: android, abstract

Welcome, I have problem with GooleMap onInfoWindowClick. 
Android show error:
"com.example.ann.myapp$1 is not abstract and doesnt not override abstract method onInfoWindowClick(Marker) in OnInfoWindowClickListener"

I dont understand it because the commented method 
setOnMarkerClickListener
works fine. I just change  setOnMarkerClickListener to
setOnWindowClickListener

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> latlngs = new ArrayList<>();
    ArrayList<ImageItem> allItems   = new ArrayList<>();

    private MarkerOptions options = new MarkerOptions();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        latlngs.add(new LatLng(54.353728,18.65954));
        latlngs.add(new LatLng(54.353001,18.657567));
        latlngs.add(new LatLng(54.353747,18.65938));

    }





    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;


        LatLng sydney = new LatLng(54.353001, 18.657567);
        mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(sydney).title("Marker in Sydney"));
        mMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLng(sydney));


// ************* here is the problem ****************
        mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public boolean onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
                //  if(arg0.getTitle().equals("MyHome")) // if marker source is clicked
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg0.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// display toast
                return true;
            }

        });

// ************* end of the problem ****************


//        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener() {
//            @Override
//            public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
//                marker.setIcon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.logo));
//                return false;
//            }
//        });



    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

void instead boolean !!!!

```
mMap.setOnInfoWindowClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnInfoWindowClickListener()
{

    @Override
    public void onInfoWindowClick(Marker arg0) {
        //  if(arg0.getTitle().equals("MyHome")) // if marker source is clicked
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), arg0.getTitle(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();// display toast

    }

});
```